# is this a keyboard hardware limitation?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, hardware, xmodmap

I have remapped <kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> on an ancient mechanical keyboard.

It is still impossible to use the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key to produce key combinations like <kbd>C-e</kbd>.

xev shows the following sequences are received when holding <kbd>caps lock</kbd> and pressing the <kbd>e</kbd> key:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x250, subw 0x0, time 125662314, (4,-16), root:(5,382),
    state 0x4, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
   root 0x250, subw 0x0, time 125663274, (4,-16), root:(5,382),
    state 0x0, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Only when holding the actual left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and pressing <kbd>e</kbd> is it producing the expected `^E` control sequence:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x250, subw 0x0, time 125666946, (4,-16), root:(5,382),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x250, subw 0x0, time 125669530, (4,-16), root:(5,382),
    state 0x4, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (05) "^E"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (05) "^E"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As it's shown that <kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd>'s XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37 I would like to know if it is possible to handle this in the event that it is a hardware limitation.

The keyboard is from an Apple IIcI, a computer was released in 1989.

What do you think could be causing this?

Comment: I don't know what an Apple IIcI is. Is it a variant of an Apple IIc? If that's what you're talking about then I am quite amazed that you are somehow using an Apple IIc with X11... but anyway I definitely remember that the caps lock key on the Apple IIc is a mechanical locking push-on-push-off switch, so not really usable as a control key unless you want to push it on and push it off.

Comment: The lock-in/lock-out mechanism is made of a small metal clip that has been removed for this reason.

Comment: How exactly did you do the remapping? It could be a hardware limitation — some keyboards do have limited support for reporting simultaneous key presses. The easiest way to rule out a software misconfiguartion is to check your configuration. If your configuration if fine then by elimination the problem is the hardware.